# Ordering events using Solspace Calendar (Craft CMS)

Tags: plugin-solspacecalendar

I'm trying to retrieve a list of events that are ordered by calendar and also event title.

I can't get any of the ordering values to have any effect.

```
set events = craft.calendar.events({
    dateRangeStart: '2017-08-27',
    dateRangeEnd: '2017-08-27',
    order: 'calendarId ASC'
})
```

All I ever get is the results by `element.id`.

The documentation says `'use any of the keys above'` and then uses a key that's not listed above. It suggests `'startDate'` which is an event property, so I'm assuming that I'd be allowed to use event `'title'`...?

I could just get all the events for the day and then group and sort in Twig but that's a terrible spot for grouping and sorting, and the docs suggest that the ordering of results works.

Does anyone know what I'm getting wrong?